# Single Use Loader

Tags: android, android-loadermanager

In the click handler for a button, I'm loading some data from a content provider (using `getContentResolver().query(...)`), then sending that data off in a network request. Since the query happens on the main thread with this approach, I want to move this off the main UI thread.

I think I can use a LoaderManager, and fire off the network request in `onLoadFinished()`, but the problem is that I don't want `onLoadFinished()` called ever again (for that Loader id), because I don't want to fire the network request again, during a screen orientation for example.

So, how do I use a LoaderManager for a query that I only want to happen only once?

Answer (score 0):

Calling `LoaderManager#initLoader()` in your `Activity#onCreate()` method will either create a new `Loader` and force a new load, or reuse an existing `Loader` and deliver the most recently queried data if any exists. So as long as you are using the `LoaderManager` correctly (i.e. the way the developer's site recommends in the documentation), you shouldn't have any problems.

Comment: The issue is that I only need the result of the query once, but using a LoaderManager, I get the result back multiple times (on screen rotate, or activity re-creation, etc).

Answer (score 0):

In your `onLoadFinished()`, you can call `getLoaderManager().destroyLoader(loaderId)` (or `getSupportLoaderManager()` as applicable). That will stop the Loader from automatically reloading. You may also need to ensure that where you are calling `initLoader` is guarded from executing again (via saving a boolean variable in `onSaveInstanceState` for example).